# Whether we can use admin_move_table move table between schema in DB2

Tags: database, database-design, db2, database-administration, db2-luw

1. I am trying to move table from STG schema to APP schema present in same tablespace using ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE stored procedure call in DB2 but there is no option to specify target schema name. Kindly let me know how to move table from one schema to another schema.
2. Kindly let me know how to move table from one schema to another schema present in different tablespace using ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE.

The requirement behind ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE is our online APP table should not drop for a seconds also. Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply create an alias for your table?

Comment: Yes. Target App tables used by Application. We can't give any alias name for tables

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand this. Why can't you use an alias, but moving a table to a different schema is OK?

Comment: My online application uses APP schema. I want to move tables from STG schema to APP schema using  ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE

Comment: Hi mustaccio,  I have 3 question Question 1) Whether  it's possible to move table from source Schema ( STG schema ) to target schema ( APP schema ) using ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE?  2) if I use 2 different table space and use ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE to move data from source table space to target table space. If Target table space already contains  same source schema name then ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE overrides the target space table or throw errors?

Comment: 3) The main reason for using ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE is while moving record from source to target, the target tables should be online. Kindly let me know whether ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE table work for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

With ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE, the target table must exist in the same schema as the source table.

That is the restrictions.
Even for 'rename table' statement, it's same and we can't change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered moving the ADMIN_MOVE_SCHEMA procedure? This will copy all of the objects from one schema to another, and allow you to put the new tables in a different tablespace. 
A second option would be to use db2move with the copy option. This would allow you to specify a list of tables from your STG schema.